# Month over month line chart with google embed api

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is it possible to have one chart that contains multiple lines representing the sessions per day in the most recent thirty day period and the previous 30 day period, in different colors?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **Embed API *Third Party Visualizations***:

[image]

You can recreate the demo from documentation: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/